# Looking for a linux terminal (not drop-down) that can rename tabs and save them including their paths

Tags: linux, terminal-emulator

I have tried terminator, I can rename the tabs but I can't save correctly the layout and state such as the current working directory. Guake is almost perfect, I can do all what I need but I also need the terminal to be in a window, not drop-down.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found ROXTerm, which does what I needed.